# remove http:// from 1 url only

Tags: javascript

i am trying to remove http:// from 1 url

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){
 var link = "http://exmaple.com/es.html?212132=http://example.com/12.jpg"
  link = link.replace(/^https?:\/\//,'');
  }
 </script>
```

so this code will remove both http:// from http://exmaple.com/es.html and http: //example.com/12.jpg

i want to remove only the http:// from http ://example.com/12.jpg

so how this can be done?

thanks

Comment: `string.replace` affects only first occurence without global flag. You also use `^` to stick match to start of string. Your get parameter value should be urlencoded by `encodeURIComponent`. You can use `replace(/=https?:\/\//, '=')`

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: replace(/=http:\/\//, '=') this work. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
link = link.replace(/=https?:\/\//,'=');
```

You basically find the *=https://* and replace it with single *=*

Comment: excess anchor `^`. just remove it.